# Python: Very slow nested for loop

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, nested

I have approx. 266680 users (the value of my `user_num` variable is 266680) and a map with user index key and business index list values. For example: `users_businesses[0] = 1,5,7,9,11,15` means that the user with index 0 has already voted the businesses with `1,5,7,9,11,15` index. My task is to create edge list between users, who have at least 5 common rated businesses.
So for example if: `users_businesses[1] = 1,5,7,9,11,13 -> (0,1)` will be an edge, because 0 and 1 users have 5 common rated businesses.

I have tried the following:

```
def Length_Elements(element_list):
    num=0
    for element in element_list:
        num=num+1
    return num

def More_Than_Five_Common_Businesses(list1, list2):
    common_elements = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
    num = Length_Elements(common_elements)
    if(num >= 5):
        return True
    return False

tuple_list = []
for user1 in range(user_num):
    for user2 in range(user_num):
        if(More_Than_Five_Common_Businesses(users_businesses[user1],users_businesses[user2])):
            tuple_list.append((user1,user2))
```

Of course this is very slow because the nested for loop iterates 266680*266680 times.
Could you give me a better solution? I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: How many `users_businesses` do you have? Is it finite number less then 266680?

Comment: I have users_business[0], users_businesses[1], ..., users_businesses[266679]. So everyone has rated a list of businesses.

Comment: I meant how many unique businesses. Your example state 15 as max

Comment: I have 157891 unique businesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter`.

Following is an experiment comparing the time taken by nested loop and filter:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import itertools

def compare(t):
    a, b = t
    return a > b

a1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=2000)

start = time.time()
result = filter(compare, itertools.product(a1, a1))
print(time.time() - start) # takes 0.0s

result2 = []
start = time.time()
for i in range(a1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a1.shape[0]):
        if a1[i] > a1[j]:
            result2.append((a1[i], a1[j]))
print(time.time() - start) # takes 5.867310285568237s

print(len(list(result))) #1979249
print(len(list(result2))) #1979249
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the best algorithm for that, but I see two problems.

First: The main loop is making double extra work. Better user some like this:

```
In [3]: for x in range(5):
   ...:     for y in range(1, 5-x):
   ...:         print x,y+x
   ...:         
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

Second: Use a programming language that you have good knowledge. [len(s)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#len), [Sequence Types — list, tuple, range](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the businesses and then connect all users that are in that business and keep count of how many times a user is connected to another user.

So in essence you need 3 for-loops:

1. The first for loop is to make a list of users per business.
2. The second for loop is to loop over the businesses and connect all the users in that business list. 
   You can do this by keeping a map of tuples for each user, with each tuple containing a user id and the number of connections.
3. The third loop loop over the users, and then for each user loop over the tuples and add an edge if the number is larger or equal to 5.

This might be faster depending on the density of the data. If each user has at least 1 connection with each other user, it is equally slow since the second and the third loop will be as slow as your original solution.